# What are the ways to get a headhunter belt in Path of Exile?

Tags: path-of-exile

This question is for Legacy League.
To get the headhunters belt unique item, I know you can use an orb of chance on a leather belt, but am unsure on the specific requirements.

Using a nemesis leaguestone, you use orb of chance on a normal quality belt, but does the belts item level matter? Can it drop from mobs in a nemesis leaguestone area? Do the normal quality belts that you chance have to be dropped from a nemesis area or would leather belts sold by vendors also be able to be chanced to headhunters?

I want to try get one even though I know odds are very slim, and I don't want to waste a bunch of chance orbs by doing it incorrectly.

Also a side question. Would you recommend using chance orbs for something else rather than headhunters? Obviously that is the most valuable unique, but would I be able to make more currency by trying to obtain something more likely to actually roll unique?

Comment: Anything unique that would sell for a high price is going to be very unlikely to be chanced. I've tried for several seasons to get skyforths through chance with no luck. Though those are about equal to headhunter in rarity as well.

Answer (score 4):

The item level of the belt does not matter.

It can drop from mobs in a nemesis leaguestone area, but I assume it's exceedingly rare.

Leather belts don't have to be obtained from the nemesis zones.

People pick up and chance Sorcerer Boots as well to try and get Skyforth.

Chancing for a specific unique is very rare. Some guy who chanced a lot of leather belts said he got a headhunter every ~7,700 leather belts on average. Just think of every leather belt that drops for you and you chance as just being a drop. Sometimes you get very lucky with drops (headhunter), and sometimes you get crap like some magic belt with bad affixes. I don't know if specifically playing to collect leather belts from vendors, buying them from people, etc. will be worth your time when you could be playing the game normally and obtaining currency reliably.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

7.700 tries with a single belt has roughly the cost of bying one. 
If you try specifically collecting white leathers then cost can drastically decrase specifically for headhunter but cost of opportunity hinders you from other things so all in all I don't think it is generally worth it apart from the challenging and rewarding part of fighting the almighty RNGesus and winning, even by a margin of 1c